# Excel macro to open a folder of excel workbooks and copy 1 cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a folder of .xlsx files, each identical in layout.

I need to write a macro in excel to open each file in turn (100+ files)
then get the data (a name) from a single cell, and drop it in a new excel worksheet, move on to the next and insert that below the last one etc.

Giving me basically a list of names from data not file names)

Answer (score 1):

Here is (pretty much) exactly what you're trying to do. Next time do a little bit of googling before you ask! :)

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/files-in-a-directory.html

***ROUGH CODE UNSURE IF IT WILL WORK:*** But here is the basic idea of what you need to modify in the example I sent you. If you look at the example again, it does everything you need and then some. Since you weren't interested in all worksheets, you don't have to loop through all worksheets in a workbook. You can just open it up, read your cell of interest, and then close it. The Do While loop will do this for every Excel file in your directory. AGAIN! Please modify this example accordingly before you use it.

```
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, i As Integer, j As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

directory = "c:\test\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")

Do While fileName <> ""

    i = i + 1
    Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
    Workbooks("files-in-a-directory.xls").Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(1).Cells(x, y) <-- whatever your cell of interest is
    Workbooks(fileName).Close
    fileName = Dir()

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Thanks i'll have a look, I did actually, quite a bit, I have tried a few but they seemed to either explode or copy the entire worksheet...

Comment: No problem! I actually had to figure out this problem a while back myself. The key is once you have the workbook open (in code), you can narrow down your search parameter to a single cell rather than just a worksheet.

Comment: Ahhh its close but not quite what I'm after, this gets the file names, what i need is the data from a certain cell.

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft Yes but you have to edit very little to do what you want it to do. I'll post an answer that should hopefully do what you need it to do.

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft any luck?

Comment: not yet, something cropped up at work, will carry on in the morning and report back!